# Not catching exception thrown by TaskEx.Run's task

Tags: c#, async-ctp

I'm having trouble with the async CTP, trying to figure out what the correct way to handle exceptions is. The code below crashes my program, when as far as I can tell, the `await` should be catching and rethrowing the exception in the context it is called from, so the `Not caught!` block should catch the exception.

```
try {
  await TaskEx.Run(() => {
    throw new Exception();
  });
} catch {
  // Not caught!
}
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me using the beta (rather than the CTP, hence the `TaskEx` becoming `Task`):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Task t = Foo();
        t.Wait();
    }

    static async Task Foo()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception(); });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bang! " + e);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Bang! System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at Test.<Foo>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter
            .HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Test.<Foo>d__2.MoveNext()
```

What does the same code do on your machine?

Comment: Huh. Looks like you're right for the CTP as well. I was confused by Visual Studio 2010's terrible debugging support for async code. VS tells me that the exception was unhandled, but if I let it continue to run, then the outer catch block does catch it after all.

Comment: Sigh! Why doesn't any literature on Tasks/async mention that VS will claim the exception is unhandled?!

Comment: This is so annoying to me.  Even with VS2012, still the same.  If you continue to run, it will catch properly, just the debugging threw me off.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pro Tip: Visual Studio is *telling* you that the exception is unhandled, but if you F5 through, you will see that it *does* get caught.

*(This from comments on Jon's answer, but I think it deserves its own answer)*

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of rearranging should work:

```
  await TaskEx.Run(() => {
    try {
      throw new Exception();
    } catch {
      // Caught!
    }
  });
```

**EDIT:**

I get the same results as [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10804684/3312) due to the fact that I'm also running the VS11 beta. I cannot speak for the CTP.